ERROR "processDebugMainManifest' in react-native
When I try to run react-native project created react-native-community/cli, with most recent react-native version of 0.75.2 many errors came. I tried many attempts, deleted and reinstalled some files and at last managed to create a blank react native app. Then, I installed the dependencies of my previous project, by yarn install xxx yyy zzz aaa bbb etc. Then when I ran the project with yarn android, this ERROR came:
Error:
        Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:22.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58
        is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:23.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <property> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute property#android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG@resource value=(@xml/ga_ad_services_config) from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:22.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-58
        is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:23.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:92:13-59 value=(@xml/gma_ad_services_config).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <property> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

EDIT: I revised my manifest file as suggested in error like this:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application tools:replace="android:resource"
...

But this error came after I ran again:
BU�LD FAILED in 9s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\react\social\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-30:19 Error: tools:replace specified at line:9 for attribute android:resource, but no new value specified C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\react\social\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error: Validation failed, exiting FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BU�LD FAILED in 9s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

How to handle this error? Also isn't there anyone trying to maintain error-free stability of newly published react-native versions? If not providing stability, why publishing new versions on each month, I don't understand.

The same happened here, I searched and found the answer. Add this lines in your app's manifest.xml file:
<property
      android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
      android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config"
      tools:replace="android:resource" />

I tested and it works.
Source: https://www.codelocker.net/p/16006/react-native-google-mobile-ads-and-androidmanifestxml-errors-androidadservicesadservicesconfig/
